# What are the likely FDs(Functional Dependencies) for this relation?

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies, relational-model

ABC(doc-firstname, doc-surname, doc-gender, doc-rego, doc-qualification, pat-ID,
pat-givename, pat-surname, pat-gender, pat-DOB, pat-addr, pat-phone, app-ID,
app-datetime, app-type)

● A doctor has a unique registration number (doc-rego) and is also described by
name, gender and qualification.

● A patient is identified by a unique patient ID (pat-ID) and has other information.

● Each appointment by a patient with a doctor is assigned a unique appointment ID
(app-ID). An appointment can be of the long or short type.

**Would these Functional dependencies work for this relation?**

fd1: doc-rego -> doc-firstname, doc-surname

fd2: patID -> pat-givename, pat-surname, pat-gender, pat-DOB, pat-addr, pat-phone

fd3: app-ID -> app-datetime, app-type

Comment: Hi. Please explain *why* you think those are the relevant FDs. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 0):

In fd1 you should add doc-qualification (asssuming that each doctor has a unique qualification).

Then, note the phrase “Each appointment by a patient with a doctor is assigned ...” implies that an appointment concerns a unique doctor and a unique patient. In other words, the app-ID, in addition to the attributes app-datetime, app-time determines also a doctor (so doc-rego) and a patient (so pat-ID), so you should modify fd3 in this way:

fd3: app-ID -> app-datatime, app-time, doc-rego, pat-ID

Comment: Maybe a doctor has many qualifications. "Described by" is vague. So is "has other information".